# Is there a way to disable line wrap in a List View in android?

Tags: android, listview, textview, line, word-wrap

I have a list view holding text views and when the text gets too big, it wraps and the item takes up two spaces. I am wondering if there is a way to turn off line wrap in this case, and if it should be done in the textview or the listview.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [`android:singleLine`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine) attribute in TextView to `true`

Answer (score 3):

*This is just a clarification (I don't have the reputation points to comment yet).*

The XML item upon which you need to set the `android:singleLine` attribute is the one used for *each individual item*, not the ListView node (which doesn't support the `android:singleLine` attribute.

The individual item TextView is the one that you'd pass to the ArrayAdapter constructor used for the ListView.